# Invalid XML Replace Content in PHP

Tags: php, xml, regex

I have a invalid XML like this

```
Warning: count() [function.count]: Node no longer exists in /var/bla/test.php
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="ISO-8859-1"?>
<nodes>
<some>test</some>
</nodes>
```

Now i need a regex which would replace the `Warning: count() [function.count]: Node no longer exists in /var/bla/test.php` with `""`
how can i do that?

The above xml is is not generated on my localmachine, its a api call which returned a invalid xml

Comment: Perhaps solving the error rather than hiding the message would be a better approach?

Comment: @nickf Reminds me of [this image](http://dl.dropbox.com/u/146967/20100422.php-vs-python.png).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Assuming you have to use a regular expression for some reason, this line of PHP removes everything from the start of the string until the first occurrence of `<?xml`:

```
$output = preg_replace('/\A.*?<\?xml/s', '<?xml', $input);
```

Answer (score 0):

`error_reporting(0);`

Comment: Its not on my local machine its from a api

Answer (score 0):

[This blog post](http://drupal.org/node/199337) might have the answer.

The short story is to cast to a string if you want to use the value of an attribute or node.

Answer (score 0):

Sticking to your question, just remove the first line of that file.